# Making the fill and clone commands easier to use

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-mods

So I've been playing with the 1.8 snapshots and now pre-release for a few months now, and the `/fill` and `/clone` commands are fantastic for a creative-prone player like myself. No longer do I have to sit around waiting for Bukkit and WorldEdit to get up to date so I can build and modify large areas.

Having used these commands extensively (along with copious amounts of scratch paper for writing down coordinates) I'm wondering: is there a way I can to simplify setting the start/end coordinates for these commands? Like WorldEdit's `//wand`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To my knowledge there are no mods like this at all, and if there were any they would not be up to date with the 1.8 prereleases/snapshots. However there are a couple of tips to making easier use of the commands:

1. Hitting `Tab` will automatically fill out the coordinates of the block you are looking at.

   [image]

   This is a much faster way of filling out coordinates than typing it in manually from the F3 screen. Hitting `Space` then `Tab` three times will correctly enter the X, Y and Z of the block your cross-hair is over.
2. `Enter` can be used to submit and "save" a half-completed command, then press `Up` while in chat to bring it back up and complete it.

   [image]

   As the command does not have the correct syntax, you will get an error message when pressing `Enter` and nothing will happen, but you can still use `Up` to get the command that you entered back.

   Using this in combination with the previous trick allows you to move and easily enter both sets of coordinates into the command, without writing or even copy pasting anything.

Comment: Hitting tab will..... ? HOLY F*